# Navbar overlap below the main canvas, not above it, z-index in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a copy of the windows calculator but in python, and I have a problem because the navbar I created instead of being displayed on the main canvas with its dimensions, displays as a short straight line as if it were overlapping the main canvas, is there any method to set z-index in python?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import W
import webbrowser

# FONTS
ERROR = ("Verdana", 15, "bold")
LARGE = ("Verdana", 30, "bold")
SMALL = ("Verdana", 15)
DIGITS = ("Verdana", 12, "bold")
DEFAULT = ("Verdana", 18)
TOGGLER_SMALL = ("Helvetica", 11, "bold")
TOGGLER_SMALL_BTN = ("Helvetica", 9)
TOGGLER_SMALL_BTN_JK = ("Helvetica", 7, "bold")



# COLORS
WHITE = "#e9ecef"
WHITE_SHADE = "#c5c6c7"
TK_LABEL = "#9d0208"


# ICONS
faviconn = ("/data/favicon/calc.ico")

class ToggleMenu(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, width=250, height=470, bg='#c5c6c7')
        self.button_callback = None
        # UI MENU
        self.create_text(50, 60, text='Calculator', anchor=tk.CENTER, font=TOGGLER_SMALL)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Standard', font=TOGGLER_SMALL_BTN, command=lambda: self.button_callback())
        self.create_window(75, 180, window=self.button)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Visit my GitHub!', font=TOGGLER_SMALL_BTN_JK, command=lambda: self.button_callback(webbrowser.open('https://github.com')))
        self.create_window(125, 450, window=self.button)

    def set_button_callback(self, callback):
        self.button_callback = callback

    def ui_start(self):
        self.place(x=0, y=0)
        
    def ui_stop(self):
        self.place_forget()

class calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("320x470")
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        self.window.title("Calculator")
        self.is_toggle_active: bool = False
        self.__ui_create()

        self.total_expression = ""
        self.current_expression = ""
        self.display_frame = self.create_display_frame()

        self.total_label, self.label = self.create_display_labels()

        self.digits = {
            7: (1, 1), 8: (1, 2), 9: (1, 3),
            4: (2, 1), 5: (2, 2), 6: (2, 3),
            1: (3, 1), 2: (3, 2), 3: (3, 3),
            '¬':(4, 1), 0: (4, 2), ',': (4, 3)
        }
        
        self.operations = {"/": "\u00F7", "*": "\u00D7", "-": "-", "+": "+"}
        self.buttons_frame = self.create_buttons_frame()

        self.buttons_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        for x in range(1, 5):
            self.buttons_frame.rowconfigure(x, weight=1)
            self.buttons_frame.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.create_digit_buttons()
        self.create_operator_buttons()
        self.create_special_buttons()
        self.bind_keys()

    def bind_keys(self):
        self.window.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.evaluate())
        for key in self.digits:
            self.window.bind(str(key), lambda event, digit=key: self.add_to_expression(digit))

        for key in self.operations:
            self.window.bind(key, lambda event, operator=key: self.append_operator(operator))

    def create_special_buttons(self):
        self.create_clear_button()
        self.create_equals_button()
        self.create_square_button()
        self.create_sqrt_button()

    def create_display_labels(self):
        total_label = tk.Label(self.display_frame, text=self.total_expression, anchor=tk.E, bg=WHITE,
                               fg=TK_LABEL, padx=24, font=SMALL)
        total_label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        label = tk.Label(self.display_frame, text=self.current_expression, anchor=tk.E, bg=WHITE,
                         fg=TK_LABEL, padx=24, font=ERROR)
        label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        return total_label, label

    def create_display_frame(self):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.window, height=221, bg=WHITE)
        frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        return frame

    def add_to_expression(self, value):
        self.current_expression += str(value)
        self.update_label()

    def create_digit_buttons(self):
        for digit, grid_value in self.digits.items():
            button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text=str(digit), bg=WHITE, fg=TK_LABEL, font=DIGITS,
                               borderwidth=0, command=lambda x=digit: self.add_to_expression(x))
            button.grid(row=grid_value[0], column=grid_value[1], sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def append_operator(self, operator):
        self.current_expression += operator
        self.total_expression += self.current_expression
        self.current_expression = ""
        self.update_total_label()
        self.update_label()

    def create_operator_buttons(self):
        i = 0
        for operator, symbol in self.operations.items():
            button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text=symbol, bg=WHITE_SHADE, fg=TK_LABEL, font=DEFAULT,
                               borderwidth=0, command=lambda x=operator: self.append_operator(x))
            button.grid(row=i, column=4, sticky=tk.NSEW)
            i += 1

    def clear(self):
        self.current_expression = ""
        self.total_expression = ""
        self.update_label()
        self.update_total_label()

    def create_clear_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="C", bg=WHITE_SHADE, fg=TK_LABEL, font=DEFAULT,
                           borderwidth=0, command=self.clear)
        button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def square(self):
        self.current_expression = str(eval(f"{self.current_expression}**2"))
        self.update_label()

    def create_square_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="x\u00b2", bg=WHITE_SHADE, fg=TK_LABEL, font=DEFAULT,
                           borderwidth=0, command=self.square)
        button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def sqrt(self):
        self.current_expression = str(eval(f"{self.current_expression}**0.5"))
        self.update_label()

    def create_sqrt_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="\u221ax", bg=WHITE_SHADE, fg=TK_LABEL, font=DEFAULT,
                           borderwidth=0, command=self.sqrt)
        button.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def evaluate(self):
        self.total_expression += self.current_expression
        self.update_total_label()
        try:
            self.current_expression = str(eval(self.total_expression))

            self.total_expression = "ERROR has occurred!"
        except Exception as e:
            self.current_expression = "ERR"
        finally:
            self.update_label()

    def create_equals_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="=", bg=WHITE_SHADE, fg=TK_LABEL, font=DEFAULT,
                           borderwidth=0, command=self.evaluate)
        button.grid(row=4, column=4, columnspan=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def create_buttons_frame(self):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.window)
        frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        return frame

    def update_total_label(self):
        expression = self.total_expression
        for operator, symbol in self.operations.items():
            expression = expression.replace(operator, f' {symbol} ')
        self.total_label.config(text=expression)

    def update_label(self):
        self.label.config(text=self.current_expression[:11])

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
        
    def ui_start(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
        
    def __ui_create(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self.window, text='Standard', font='Verdana 15')
        self.label.pack()
        self.toggle_menu = ToggleMenu(self.window)
        self.toggle_menu.set_button_callback(self.__toggle_callback)
        self.button_toggle = tk.Button(self.window, text='\u2630', command=self.__button_toggle_handler)
        self.button_toggle.place(x=0, y=0)
        
    def __button_toggle_handler(self):
        if self.is_toggle_active:
            self.toggle_menu.ui_stop()
            self.is_toggle_active = False
        else:
            self.toggle_menu.ui_start()
            self.is_toggle_active = True
            
    def __toggle_callback(self):
        print('echo test')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calculatormain = calculator()
    calculatormain.run()
    calculatormain.ui_start()
```

I would like the navbar to be displayed on the main window.

Comment: It would help if you could reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about the layout of the navbar, we don't need all of the calculator buttons or functions.

Comment: if you run `self.__ui_create()`  after `self.create_display_frame()` then you get it on top. But you will have to create `Label(self.window, text='Standard'` before `self.create_display_frame()`

Answer (score 0):

If you create object in different order then you get it on top.

You have to run `__ui_create()` as last element but `Label(self.window, text='Standard')` has to be created as first

`__ui_create()` has to be also before `bind_keys()` but I didn't check why.

```
        self.label = tk.Label(self.window, text='Standard', font='Verdana 15')
        self.label.pack()
       
        # ... other ...

        self.__ui_create()

        self.bind_keys()
```

[image]

[image]